# A More Efficient SQL Query method needed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with data in it as such

```
UID UPN Reg Surname Forename    Class   Teacher     Subject code    Points
1   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe PU/Thu:1    Mrs A RIGNALL   Ph            5
2   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10u/En2     Mr D THORNBER   En            2
3   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10u/Ma1     Miss J ANDERSON Ma            4
4   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10u/Pe1     Ms J L SHARPLES Pe            4
5   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10u/Re1     Ms  M HURST     Re            3
6   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10u/Bi1     Mrs A RIGNALL   Bi            5
7   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10u/Ch1     Mrs  ARIGNALL   Ch            0
8   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10A/Pa1     Miss O NELSON   Pa            1
9   UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10B/Hi1     Miss C MEDOWS   Hi            2
10  UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10C/Gg1     Mr A  RHODES    Gg            10
11  UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe 10ux/Ps1    Mrs B TAYLOR    Ps            5
12  UPN111  10B BLOGGS  Joe CLS 11F     Mrs L ROBINSON                6
```

I need to display each person by UPN in a table with classes as columns for a whole form.

Each table cell Row X Column has a form element with the points in which is then editable for an update.

The code I have for this seems very slow at pulling all the data from the msyql database, this has been since I added the query to get the points data.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table 2` WHERE `Reg` = '".$_GET['f']."' group by `UPN`");
$squery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `Subject Code` FROM `table 2`");
$dquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table 2` WHERE `Reg` = '".$_GET['f']."'");

echo "<form><table>";
echo "<tr><td>Name</td>";

//HEADER
while($subjecth = mysql_fetch_array($squery)){
echo "<td>|".$subjecth['Subject Code']."</td>";
}

//DATA
while($form = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$form['Forename']." ".$form['Surname']."</td>";


$pquery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `Subject Code` FROM `table 2`");
while($subjects = mysql_fetch_array($pquery)){
$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table 2` WHERE `UPN` = '".$form['UPN']."' AND `Subject Code` = '".$subjects['Subject Code']."'"));
if($data['Points'] == NULL){
    echo "<td></td>";
}
else {
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=".$form['UPN']."-".$subjects['Subject Code']." size=\"3\" value=\"".$data['Points']."\"></td>";
}
}
}
echo "</table></form>";
```

Is there a more efficient way to query the data I need and insert it into the page?

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: The data is not readable

Comment: Is the data retrieval slow when performing this query outside of PHP? Have you done an `EXPLAIN` query to see how the table is being searched? Are indexes optimized?

Comment: pulling the data from the table isn't slow outside of the coding, it seems to be the query within the "while" loop that causes the slow running as it would be doing about 1000 queries for the points data.

Comment: It is slow because the number of times you execute your points query is equal to `(rows returned by $query * rows returned by $pquery)`. This is a horribly inefficient method of getting data.

Comment: I know its inefficient,  but every other way I know to query the DB doesnt return the correct data for the points.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the jargon for the table you're attempting to display is a "pivot" table, where certain rows (`class` in your case) are pivoted so they are columns. Knowing that may help you find appropriate tutorials. Some RDMS systems / not MySQL / support pivot tables in their query systems.

Hint: don't use oddball characters like spaces in column names. It condemns you to using blizzards of backticks in your queries.

Hint: don't use `SELECT *` in general. It fetches data which you then discard. That slows things down.

Fewer queries are better, even if the result sets contain some repetitive data. It seems you need a column per subject. So, I suggest you fetch yourself a list of those subjects to start, and put it into an array.

```
$subject_position = Array();
$position = 0;
$pquery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `Subject Code` FROM `table 2` ORDER BY `Subject Code`");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($pquery)){
    $sub = $result['Subject Code'];
    $subject_position[$sub] = $position;
    $position = $position + 1;
}
```

Then, issue a query fetching all the results you need in a single result set, ordered by upn, then by subject. Work through the rows of that result set. Whenever the upn changes, start a new table.

For each row, you can fetch the subject, then look up the subject position in the `$subject_position` array.